# Timezone for Plugin

Tags: date, date-time, timestamp, offsets, timezones

I'm using these two lines:

```
$expires = strtotime( $_POST['expire_date']);
if($expires < time())
```

to test the time in the `name=expire_date` form against GMT time. But no matter what I do my expire date time is 5 hours off. I'm in GMT -5, so I'm trying to adjust the top line:

```
$expires = strtotime( $_POST['expire_date']) - (( get_option( 'gmt_offset' ) * HOUR_IN_SECONDS ));
```

But it's not working. Any ideas for correct GMT offset handling in Wordpress?

Comment: [`current_time('timestamp')` is deprecated because it's super confusing](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/40657).

Comment: oh interesting. I'll update. It seems like time() returns the same